# Equal spacing between elements in jqmobile listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, listview

I am creating a jquery mobile listview dynamically and would like to have different elements on same line with specific spacing. Each element would then line up in each succeeding list item (it looks tabular). I can use span to add a margin between elements but the problem is when the of length text is different it shifts the element.

Here is the code I use to create the listview

```js
if (i == 0) {
content = "<div data-role='collapsible' data-theme='a'><h3>Date<span style='float:right;' class='ui-btn-up-c  ui-btn-corner-all cnt'>Count</span></h3><ul data-role='listview' data-theme='b'><li><a rel='external' href='#'><span style='margin-right:30px'>Test Text</span>Next Element</a></li>"
temprec = rec[1];
}
else {
if (rec[1] == temprec) {
content = content + "<li><a rel='external' href='#'><span style='margin-right:30px'>Long Long Test Text</span>Next Element</a></li>"
}
else {
content = content + "</ul></div><div data-role='collapsible' data-theme='a'><h3>Date<span style='float:right;' class='ui-btn-up-c  ui-btn-corner-all cnt'>Count</span></h3><ul data-role='listview' data-theme='b'><li><a rel='external' href='#'><span style='margin-right:30px'>Text</span>Next Element</a></li>"
temprec = rec[1];
}
}​
```

Here is example current of output (I tried to attach picture)...

Text     Next Element

Long Long Test Text     Next Element

Long Long Test Text     Next Element

Long Long Test Text     Next Element

I would like all the "Next Element" text to lineup in a column. Is there a way to do that? 
Thank you!

Comment: Why not use the CSS table display options. Some output HTML to work with would be useful.

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D, which table display options? I have tried some. Not sure what you mean by output html...

Comment: See answer below. Output HTML means what HTML do you have? You haven't shown us the actual HTML we're trying to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Without some output HTML it's hard know how to advise you best but since this data is, apparently, somewhat tabular then CSS tables would seem to offer the most likely solution.

EG

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="child">Short Text</div>
    <div class="child">Next Element</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae ab.</div>
    <div class="child">Next Element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Whether this is adaptable to your specific situation is dependent, as I mentioned, on the actual HTML and whther than can, if necessary be adapted.

Comment: Thank you, the actual html I use is in the code I provided. I append that code to an element dynamically. I guess I could use a table instead of a listview but was hoping to use jquery mobile listview.

Comment: "the actual html I use is in the code I provided"...not really it's not. To help much more we'd need HTML such as the demo code I provide with base `ul / li` etc and internal elements applied dynamically"...just a demo is all we need.

Comment: Perhaps you could add that to your Code in the original question rather than here in a comment.

Comment: thank you! As soon as I add jquery mobile refernce the spacing disappears https://jsfiddle.net/GoPre400/zw8kk2cs/15/

Comment: Obviously there is some conflict....thats why we ask for demos with the actual HTML & CSS.

Comment: Thank you! I tweaked your fiddle a little and got what I wanted - https://jsfiddle.net/GoPre400/zw8kk2cs/26/